# Displaying users data in ionic 3 from firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire

I have a problem with .val() property.

**this.userProfile = profile.val(); <<<< here is the problem**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../../providers/auth/auth.service";
import { DataService } from "../../providers/data/data.service";
import { User } from 'firebase/app'
import { Profile } from "../../models/profile/profile.interface";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import { getQueryValue } from "@angular/core/src/view/query";
import { USER_LIST } from "../../mocks/profiles/profile";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile-view',
    templateUrl: 'profile-view.component.html'
})

export class ProfileViewComponent implements OnInit {

    userProfile: Profile;
     
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
           this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
                this.data.getProfile(user).valueChanges().subscribe(profile => {
                  this.userProfile = <Profile>profile.val(); <<<< here is the problem>>>>>>   

            })
        })
```

**and this is the profile-interface**

```js
export interface Profile {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
avatar: string;
email: string;
dateOfBirth: Date;


}
```

**and this is profile.ts from /mocks**

```js
import { Profile } from '../../models/profile/profile.interface';

const userList: Profile[] = [
{firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
{firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
{firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },
{firstName: 'ahmed', lastName: 'hallaq', email: 'a.m.hq@hotmail.com', avatar: 'assets/img/avatar.png', dateOfBirth: new Date() },


];

export const USER_LIST = userList;
```

this from the html file i want it to show the first name from the database

```html
<ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input [value]="userProfile.firstNAme" [readonly]="true"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

When i do ionic serve, it gives me [[profile.val is not a function]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using .val()? It couldn't be a function of profile, you even show the Profile interface, which does not have a val() function.

Can you just set it like this? Whats the value of profile in the subscription?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.data.getProfile(user)
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe((profile: Profile) => {
                 this.userProfile = profile; 
                 // What is the value of profile? Console log it? Debug it?
    })
})
```